# A complete classification of symmetry groups on the plane

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. By $Sym(S)$, I denote the group, under composition, of the set of isometries of the real plane that map $S$ to $S$. What is the complete classification of groups $G$ that are of the form $Sym(S)$ for some set $S$? In particular, is there some finite group that is not of that form? What kind of groups are possible, exactly?

Comment: Have you heard of the seventeen wallpaper groups?

Comment: @Empy2: The wallpaper groups are only partially relevant here: given a wallpaper group $G$, you likely can find a set $S$ such that $G$ is the group of planar isometries that map $S$ to $S$, but that doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: the symmetry group of an $n$-gon is a dihedral group not a cyclic group.

Comment: @user107952: I think you are getting votes to close because you haven't said much about your work on the problem or on the context. I think your question is interesting, so please address those concerns.

Comment: @RobArthan Forgot about reflections! Anyway , it still shows that some groups work out. That provides examples of non-candidates, though. I cannot imagine a set $S$ such that $\mathbb Z_3$ or $\mathbb Z_5$ to be isomorphic to $Sym(S)$. This question is interesting, so thanks for asking OP to provide context.

Comment: @Teresa it should be fairly easy to force $\operatorname{Sym}(S)\sim\mathbb Z_3$ by letting $S$ be the corners of two equilateral triangles with the same center, rotated in such a way that the reflections are distinct and only the rotations remain in common.

Comment: @MvG Nice idea! I will think about this more.